# What is the purpose of chromedriver or IEDriverServer while executing in this browsers respectively?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to know how exactly this chromedriver.exe and IEDriverServer.exe play role in executing the WebDriver scripts in chrome and IE browsers respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files above, as their name implies, are the drivers that make selenium talk to the real chrome and IE browsers on the machine running selenium tests.

There is no need for a separate firefox driver, as it comes included as part of selenium webdriver. This is also the case for the HtmlUnit driver.

When IE or Chrome browsers get updated and some functionality in tests breaks, checking if a new version of the drivers above has been produced may fix the issue.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-s-drivers